# Is the "y" necessary in "Allons-y"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

If I was to say *Let's go!* in French, could I simply say *Allons!* or would it be grammatically necessary to say *Allons-y!* ? Is there any difference in tone or meaning, if both are correct?

Comment: *Allez, on y va!* in everyday language. But notice *allez* is just an interjection here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tout d'abord, les deux expressions sont correctes.

« Allons-y » exprime un mouvement. Le *-y* est ici utilisé pour mentionner un lieu. De plus, le locuteur est inclus dans l'action, il se rend quelque part avec d'autres personnes. On peut remplacer facilement le *-y* par n'importe quel lieu :

> Allons à la gare.

On peut rajouter le point d'exclamation comme ceci : « Allons-y ! » pour exprimer une réelle motivation de se rendre dans le lieu.

« Allons » n'a rien à voir avec l'action de se déplacer. Cela exprime le rappel à l'ordre d'une personne :

> Allons Paul, tu pourrais faire des efforts !

Comment: Voilà.  On utilise le pronom _y_ pour remplacer les phrases qui commencent avec _à_ (ci-inclus au, à la, à l' et aux) et d'autres prépositions c.f. _de_ (également du, de la, de l', d et des ;  là je souligne l'article partitif.

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly enough, if you wanted to drop the *-y*, you'd have to use "Allez !", which is the 2nd person plural. Please note that by using "Allons-y !" you will include yourself in the movement, whereas "Allez" can be understood as an order to start moving, with you staying right where you are.

"Allez !" is also commonly used for cheering, in a sports event for example ("Allez les Bleus ! Allez ! Allez !")

"Allons!" is used in a totally different context. It's meant to ask your interlocutor to be serious, more reasonable.

Comment: Why doesn't *Allez!* require *y* ?

Comment: Bon, il s'agit de l'usage.  Si ça veut dire plutôt figuratif "Come on!" on dirait --Allons ! pour exprimer de l'impatience ("Bon, ben, arrête, on rigole moins") ou afin de souligner l'importance de la tâche, disons.

Comment: @Gilles : merci pour le formattage, c'est difficile de se débarrasser des habitudes de stackoverflow quand je passe sur FL&U ;)

Comment: Est-ce que je me trompe, ou c'est possible de dire "allez-y!" et non pas seulement "Allez!"?

Comment: C'est possible, mais dans ce cas cela indique clairement que le locuteur ne s'inclut pas dans le mouvement, au contraire de "Allons-y !" ou "Allez !", même si ce dernier est un peu plus ambigü.

Answer (score 3):

To put it in more linguistic term, in most uses, the verb *aller* is [divalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_%28linguistics%29), requiring an object in a form of a location ("indirectly transitive", *transitif indirect* in traditional French grammar). Because in this meaning, the verb has not lexicalised, the "dummy" object pronoun is required; it acts much like the *il* of an impersonal verb, being required by syntax, not semantics.